# In this javascript code, console.log shows "native code" for the resolve function -- where is this code?

Tags: javascript

In the code below when the console.log statement is executed I see:
resolve: function () { [native code] }

My question simply is, is the code part of the Promise definition and how did the resolve parameter get associated with this "native code" if that is true?

EDIT: My question is not about seeing the native code but the way the code gets associated with the resolve parameter.

```
/* ES5, using Bluebird */
var isMomHappy = true;

// Promise
var willIGetNewPhone = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        if (isMomHappy) {
            var phone = {
                brand: 'Samsung',
                color: 'black'
            };
            console.log("resolve: "+resolve);
            resolve(phone);
        } else {
            var reason = new Error('mom is not happy');
            reject(reason);
        }

    }
);


// call our promise
var askMom = function () {
    willIGetNewPhone
        .then(function (fulfilled) {
            // yay, you got a new phone
            console.log(fulfilled);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // ops, mom don't buy it
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}

askMom();
```

Comment: Because a native `Promise` object passes (a reference to) its native `resolve` function to your handler?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: How in general is the native resolve passed to the handler?

Comment: Ah, for that you would need to read the native code... (or the spec as mentioned in the answer by T.J. Crowder)

Answer (score 1):

> ...is the code part of the Promise definition

Yes, exactly. And that definition is built into the JavaScript engine itself. Depending on the JavaScript engine, promises may be implemented in JavaScript itself, or C++, or something else, but regardless they're "native code" in the JavaScript engine which isn't exposed by `Function.prototype.toString`.

> ...and how did the `resolve` parameter get associated with this "native code" if that is true?

When you call `new Promise`, you're calling the JavaScript engine's native promise feature. That feature calls the function you pass in (the *promise executor function*) with `resolve` and `reject` functions it creates (from native code), so you can resolve or reject the promise.

More in [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-executor), though it's fairly heavy-going...

Comment: It took me a while to find a way to ask this question about promises. Initially I thought that the end-user code which passes the function to the Promise ctor also must define the resolve function and the reject function but, finally, it looks like resolve is part of Promises definition and gets "bound" (is that right) to the parameters within the function passed to the ctor?

Comment: @Jeff - Yes, that's basically it. Just like, say, the `map` function on arrays is a "native" function provided by the engine and accessible via the `Array.prototype.map` property, the function to resolve your promise is provided by the engine and accessible in your executor function because it's passed as the argument for your `resolve` parameter when the engine's promise code calls your executor. In the `resolve` case, it's a function the engine just created [probably a wrapper around an existing one], but other than that the situations are the same.

Comment: Does it make sense to ask then why the executor passed to the Promise ctor even *needs* resolve and reject as arguments?

Comment: @Jeff - How else would you resolve or reject the promise? :-) There's nothing on the promise object itself that does that (which is by design: that way, you can give the promise to other code, and that other code can't interfere with how it's settled).

Comment: What I mean is, why can't you just invoke resolve and reject in the executor without specifying them as arguments? I can understand that might be the only way that resolve/reject can be bound to the resolve/reject of Promise, I guess.

Comment: @Jeff - You mean, why aren't they syntax rather than arguments that get passed in? I guess the answer is...why complicate things? :-) Also, this is more flexible: Suppose I have a reusable executor function. I can do `new Promise(reuseableExecutor)` and it works. If `resolve` and `reject` were special syntax only allowed in certain places, I couldn't do that.